# Differentiate between default and created users

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

Oracle creates some users default when it creates database for instance SYS and SYSTEM. Is there any way to determine whether a user is a default user in a query?

[Refer here for the default users list.](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Database_Administration/DBA_26.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

Not explicitly (that I know of). To find information about users you have to look at the system view [DBA_USERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5081.htm#REFRN23302).

You could do it on tablespace finding all users where the default tablespace is one you created; or you could simply list the default users in an IN statement:

```
select *
  from dba_users
 where username not in ('SYS','SYSTEM',...)
```

My preferred method would be to use the date the user was created. By definition a default user is created with the database so every user created after a certain date is not a default user.

On the database I'm currently connected to the following would work; you'd obviously have to alter the date portions of this to fit your own environment

```
select *
  from dba_users
 where trunc(created) > to_date('2009/08/15','yyyy/mm/dd')
```